# How to run a css code for an unknown number of css elements

Tags: css

I want to run a css code for some elements which are generated from a php while loop so the number of elements can't be specified.
Let's say this is my css for each element

```
.element {
    position: absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    z-index:100;
    margin-left:50px;
}
```

But this arrange all the elements on the same spot. But I need the elements to look like this image below [image]

So I want the height of each element to be 200 - (20 * childIndex) the margin-left to be 50 * childIndex and the z-index to be 1000 - childIndex. Please how do I run my css code?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to in-line style those elements via PHP inside your while loop. That should do the trick. If you can provide your code then we can give you further tips&advices

Comment: I don't want to do inline css. I know it can be done in normal css

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :

```css
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .container, div{
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background-color: yellow;
   border: red solid 4px;
  }
  .container {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
  }
  .container div {
   height: calc(100% - 20px);
   position: absolute;
   margin-left: 20px;
   top: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As per my understanding you want nested element so `z-index to be 1000 - childIndex` will not be possible as `z-index` will work for same level element not nested elements